# Why does $str1 not contain $str2? (PHP strpos)

Tags: php, strpos

The code:

```
<?php
$str1 = "subidubidu";
$str2 = "subi";

if(strpos($str1,$str2)){
echo "Contains!";
}else{
echo "Not contains!";
} 
?>
```

The result is "Not contains", and I'm curious about why exactly?
May it be the problem, that "subi" is at the index of[0], and 0 returns with false? Any idea?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct. But the problem is here:

**Explanation:**

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function return the index of containing string. And in your case, it is returning **0** as index of string. And 0 means false in programming. That's why your code executing else part.

In case, if your string will be at the position of 1 or 2 and so on then code will work fine. But this will be false as the matching string is at 0th position.

For future prospect, you have to put the value in a variable like this:

```
$str1 = "subidubidu";
$str2 = "subi";    
$pos = strpos($str1, $str2);

if ($pos != '' || $pos !== false) {
   echo 'Found it';
} else {
   echo 'Not found.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps

```
$str1 = "subidubidu";
$str2 = "subi";    

if (strpos($str1, $str2) !== FALSE)
    {
     echo 'Found it';
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'Not found.';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$str1 = "subidubidu";
$str2 = "subi";

if (strpos($str1, $str2)!==false) {
    echo "Contains!";
} else {
    echo "Not contains!";
}
```

You are looking for this --- strpos returns position if found and false if not

Comment: Thank you I knew how to solve it, I just wanted to know the logic behind it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected 
>   because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.

It states that you can't just use the `==` comparison which is what you are doing when you type

```
if (strpost($str1, $str2)) { .. }
```

You need to use the `===`. So it would look like:

```
<?php

$str1 = "subidubidu";
$str2 = "subi";

if (strpos($str1, $str2)!==false) {
    echo "Contains!";
} else {
    echo "Not contains!";
}
```